# Db2 ibm_db (Python): How to connect using a JWT access token?

Tags: python, jwt, db2, db2-luw

In the [Db2 Python driver the connect API](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/wiki/APIs#ibm_dbconnect) is as follows.

```
import ibm_db
#use connection string
conn=ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=database;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;PWD=password",'','')
```

What parameters would I need to utilize the [token authentication](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c_token_auth.html) introduced in Db2 LUW 11.5.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to be on the Db2 client with a minimum of 11.5.4. The connection string needs to have the following JWT- or token-related keywords (found in the [list of CLI/ODBC configuration keywords](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r_access_tokentype_config.html)):

- **AUTHENTICATION**=TOKEN
- **ACCESSTOKENTYPE**=JWT
- **ACCESSTOKEN**= with the actual JWT value

Putting it into action, the following code snippet works to successfully connect using a JWT:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import ibm_db, os

# get token from environment    
TOKEN=os.getenv("TOKEN","invalid")
connstring="""DATABASE=testdb;HOSTNAME=localhost;PORT=50000;
              AUTHENTICATION=TOKEN;ACCESSTOKEN={};ACCESSTOKENTYPE=JWT""".format(TOKEN)
conn=ibm_db.connect(connstring,'','')
if conn:
    print ("Connection succeeded.")
    ibm_db.close(conn)
else:
    print("failed")
```